# How to calculate resolution based on megapixels and aspect ratio

Tags: c#, image, resolution

How can I calculate in C# the exact resolution based on megapixels?

Let's say I have a 5000x4000 pixels image and I want to rescale to 0.6mpx, how can I get the exact horizontal and vertical resolution to get an image of 0.6mpx keeping the original aspect ratio?

I have this:

```
int nXPixels=5000;  // original image Width
int nYPixels=4000;  // original image Height
float fRatio=5000/4000;    // original image aspect ratio
int nNewPixelResolution=600000; // 0.6mpx new resolution

int nNewXPixels=?
int nNewYPixels=?
```

Comment: The answer to this question was found in a 2 second Google search:  http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180804/how-to-get-the-aspect-ratio-of-an-image

Comment: @durbnpoisn Not really; that doesn't mention anything about area (or megapixellage).

Comment: Actually @durbnpoisn, your link doesn't provide the answer.  The OP wants to specify the output MegaPixels (total pixles of wxh) rather than an output width or height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int nXPixels=5000;  // original image Width
int nYPixels=4000;  // original image Height
//float fRatio=5000/4000;    // original image aspect ratio
int nNewPixelResolution=600000; // 0.6mpx new resolution
int nOldPixelResolution=nXPixels*nYPixels;
double conv = Math.sqrt((double)nNewPixelResolution/(double)nOldPixelResolution);
int nNewXPixels= (int)Math.round(nXPixels*conv);
int nNewYPixels= (int)Math.round(nYPixels*conv);
```

Comment: If that was the case then we just need to cast the two integers to (float) first.  I've updated the code.

Comment: `conv` is 0 because he is dividing the new resolution to the old one, and he's performing an `int` division, which has the result 0 (since the new resolution is smaller than the older one). Replace `float` with `double` and add a `1.0` inside the brackets like so : `double conv=Math.Sqrt(1.0*nNewPixelResolution/nOldPixelResolution)`. This will force the division to be of result type double, since at least one of the numbers is double)

Answer (score 3):

Amount of megapixels is equal to the product of the length and width of the resolution, divided by 1 million. So for your 5000x4000 pixels, you would have 20 Mpx. To rescale it to 0.6Mpx, but keeping the ratio, you would just need to rescale each dimension by the squareroot of 20Mpx/0.6Mpx, so that, when the newly computed dimensions will be multiplied, the result would be equal to 0.6Mpx

So your computation should be similar to :

```
ratio=sqrt(20/0.6)
newWidth=oldWidth/ratio
newHeight=oldHeight/ratio
```

If you then multiply `newWidth` with `newHeight`, the result should be aproximately 0.6Mpx, or 600000 px